# How to Update Firebase Database where certain Email exists in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have searched the docs and stack overflow questions but am unable to find the answer I am looking for.

I have registered users in the database and I want to update the child where the same email exists(If a user chooses to change their details aka name and number then the details should be updated where the email is "`user_email`").

If the same email doesn't exist then it should create a new user. But my problem is that it only updates the most recent `userid` and doesn't search the entire database for the email.

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pggR.png)

Here is the RegisterActivity where the `UpdateUser()` is called and the `CreateNewUser()` is called:

```
          final String newnum = mob.getText().toString().trim();
            final String n = Name.getText().toString().trim();
            final String p = pass.getText().toString().trim();
            if (Name.getText().toString().equals("") || 
              pass.getText().toString().equals("") || 
       email.getText().toString().equals("") || 
                  mob.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all 
            the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (mob.getText().toString().length() < 10 || mob.getText().toString().length() > 10) {
                mob.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
           }
     else {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
               final String u_id = userc.getUsername();
              if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
     DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();                         
         ref.child("users").child(u_id).child("Email").
            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText
      (getApplicationContext(), "Username already exists. Please try again! 
          Or change your details if you wish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             userc.updateUser(u_id, n, e, newnum);
                                                finish();
         }
     }
     @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
       {
       }
       }); 
       }
           final String userid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("email", e);
                                 editor.putString("phoneno", newnum);
                                 editor.putString("Name",n);
                                editor.putString ("Password", p);
                                editor.commit();
                                userc.writeNewUser(userid, n, e, newnum);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                          }
```

User Activity where the methods exist:

```
    public class User{

        private DatabaseReference database = 
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
      public static String FB_REFERENCE_USER = "user";
      public String username;
      public String email;
     public String pno;
     public String n;
      String uid;

    public User() {

        }

//public String getUsername() {return username;}
     public String getPno() {
       return pno;
         }
        public String getN() {return n;}
       public String getUsername() {return username;}


     public String getEmail() {
      return email;
         }

public User( String username, String n,  String email, String pno) {
  this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.pno=pno;
   this.n=n;
}


public void writeNewUser( String uid, String name, String email, String pno)
       {
   // 
   database.child("users").child(uid).child("Username").setValue(username);
    database.child("users").child(uid).child("Email").setValue(email);
    //database.child("users").child(uid).child("PhoneNumber").setValue(pno);
   database.child("users").child(uid).child("Name").setValue(name);
    database.child("users").child(uid).child("Phone Number").setValue(pno);
}


public void updateUser(String uid, String name, String email, String pno) {
    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(FB_REFERENCE_USER);
    User u = new User(uid, name, email,pno);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = u.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put(uid, postValues);

    myRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);

}

private Map<String,Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
 //   result.put("Username", username);
    result.put("Name", n);
    result.put("Email", email);
    result.put("Phone Number", pno);

    return result;
       }
       }
```

Comment: use query for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,this is exactly what you looking for

```
private void updateUser(String name, String email) {
        // updating the user via child nodes
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
            mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("name").setValue(name);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("email").setValue(email);
    }
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: thank u. But it still only updates the most recent user. It doesnt search the database for the user with that email and instead it changes the data values of the most recent user. For example : a recent user with email "abcd" is added. Then when diff values for email "efg" is entered, it should search the database for email "efg" and update all values in that child instead of changing all the values of the most recent user

Comment: for searching you need to filter data using query in firebase database

Comment: i want to update the data where email is so n so. how should i do tht? pls help

Comment: on you app launch fetch all the data and store it arraylist, then search for perticular data, and then fire update operation.